# How can I include a header file in, but the header file I include includes the file I want to include

Tags: c++, header, include

I can't really describe my problem, so I'll show you here with code what I mean:

boxcollider.h

```cpp
#include "sprite.h"

class BoxCollider
{
public:
   BoxCollider(Sprite sprite);
};
```

sprite.h

```cpp
#include "boxcollider.h"

class Sprite
{
 public:
   BoxCollider coll;
};
```

INCLUDE issue. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As it stands, your classes have circular dependency. You *could* get round this by changing the `BoxCollider` constructor so that it takes a *reference* to the `Sprite` object and then just forward-declare `class Sprite;` in the BoxCollider header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues. One is the circular references between the two classes. The other is just the circular includes. That one is easy.

All your includes -- ALL of them -- should guard against multiple includes. You can do this two ways.

```
#ifndef BOXCOLLIDER_H
#define BOXCOLLIDER_H

// All your stuff

#endif // BOXCOLLIDER_H
```

However, all modern C++ compilers I've used support this method:

```
#pragma once
```

As the first line in the file. So just put that line at the top of all your include files. That will resolve the circular includes.

It doesn't fix the circular references. You're going to have to use a forward declaration and pass in a reference, pointer, or smart pointer instead of the raw object.

```
class Sprite;
class BoxCollider
{
public:
   BoxCollider(Sprite & sprite);
};
```

BoxCollider.h should NOT include Sprint.h, but the .CPP file should.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using *forward referencing*. This would work as follows:

boxcollider.h

```
#ifndef boxcollider(Any word you like but unique to program)
#define boxcollider(same word as used earlier)

#include "sprite.h"

class BoxCollider
{
public:
   BoxCollider(Sprite sprite);
};

#endif
```

sprite.h

```
#ifndef sprite(Any word you like but unique to program)
#define sprite(same word as used earlier)

class BoxCollider;

class Sprite
{
 public:
   BoxCollider& coll; // reference or (smart)pointer
};
#endif
```

Also don't forget the import guards. These prevent you from importing a file more than once.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the reference in the `BoxCollider` c'tor, like `BoxCollider(Sprite& sprite);`, rather than having a (permanent) reference member in `Sprite` that may become dangling?

Comment: That's definitly a valid point, but it's not known whether the relationship is a "IS-A" or "HAS-A". So a reference migth be needed. Further, when using a smart pointer you don't have any issue with dangeling pointers.

Comment: Not entirely true - if the `Sprite` c'tor takes a reference to an existing `BoxCollider`, initializes its member with that, and that source object is later deleted, then what does the reference member then refer to?

Comment: Forgot about that caveat, will remove reference from the comment.